Discord.py won't detect messages and $hello doesn't work
I have a python discord bot where all the console inputs work, but it just won't react to messages sent in discord. The bot itself is meant to print responses sent in discord to the console (if it's in a channel the bot has access to) and in DMs and things. The console allows commands to be inputted to send things into discord.
import discord
import os
import asyncio

cchannel = 1257783751249891361
cdm = 962026630497321000

token = os.environ['toke']

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    print(message.content)

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

async def command_loop():
    while True:
        global cchannel
        global cdm
        commando = input("$ ")
        commandy = commando.split(" ", 1)
        command = commando.split(" ", 1)[0]
        if command == "exit":
            print("Shutting down the bot...")
            await client.close()
            break
        elif command == "say":
            print(commandy[1])
            cchannel2 = await client.fetch_channel(cchannel)
            await cchannel2.send(commandy[1])
        elif command == "setchannel":
            print(commandy[1])
            cchannel = commandy[1]
        elif command == "setdm":
            print(commandy[1])
            cdm = commandy[1]
        elif command == "dm":
            print(commandy[1])
            cdm2 = await client.fetch_user(cdm)
            await cdm2.send(commandy[1])
        else:
            print(f"Command received: {command}")

async def main():
    bot_task = asyncio.create_task(client.start(token))
    loop_task = asyncio.create_task(command_loop())

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        [bot_task, loop_task],
        return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED
    )

    for task in pending:
        task.cancel()

asyncio.run(main())

I thought it might be the while true loop but I tried to run it in a thread and the problem still persists. No errors are thrown, it just doesn't work.
